# Apps Script Google Calendar API Integration Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

EDIT: I found a solution. Found the code below on another forum and it seemed to do the trick. Thanks

```
 if (description && startTime && endTime) {  // Added
if (eventCal.getEvents(startTime, endTime).length == 0) {  // Added
  eventCal.createEvent(description, startTime, endTime);
```

I'm building a custom calendar with excel and googles app script. Although I am having an issue with the follow code and error. any help would be appreciated!

```
function sheet2calendar() {
  
  // Set up sheet and calendar
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarID = spreadsheet.getRange("J5").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);
  

  
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A3:E23").getValues();

  for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {

    var event = signups[x];
    
    var date = event[0];
    var startTime = event[1];
    var currency  = event[2];
    var impact = event[3];
    var report = event[4];
   
    eventCal.createEvent(report, currency, impact, date,  startTime); 

        
      }
    }
```

9:54:24 PM
Notice
Execution started
9:54:24 PM
Error
Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,(class),(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent.

Comment: I think that in your question when the sample values of `signups` for correctly replicating your issue can be seen, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: Could you add your solution as an answer? This might help other users who encounter the same problem.